# Can't update user interface in NSURLSession delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurlsession

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask
 *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    float progress = (float)((float)totalBytesWritten /(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    self.progressView.progress = progress;
    self.progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%", progress*100];
}
```

I'm downloading a file via NSURLSession added in iOS 7. Everything works so far, but for some reason the user interface doesn't update. I've checked that the method is being called and I can also NSLog the progress.

Maybe because this method is called so often? But how do you update your user interface, e.g. if you have a progress bar then? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: NSURLSession runs in background thread by default, so you need to call your UI update on main thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSURLSession runs in background thread by default, so you need to call your UI update on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // perform on main
    float progress = (float)((float)totalBytesWritten /(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    self.progressView.progress = progress;
    self.progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%", progress*100];
});
```

Comment: @Martin.Koles, before I saw your answer I was researching this in the docs, but could not find an explicit statement that the NSURLSession delegate methods are called from a background thread. Do you know if the docs state this explicitly somewhere? (Granted, it's implied by the fact that NSURLSession is intended for background downloading, but still. The docs should explicitly state that a method will be called from the background and so needs to be thread-safe.)

Comment: @DuncanC, no, I haven't seen it in the docs, just assumed it by the nature of the class and what I've read and heard. Good reading is this: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession.html

Answer (score 0):

In comments to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2081268/martin-koles)'s answer, [Duncan C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c) asked

> (I) could not find an explicit statement that the NSURLSession
>   delegate methods are called from a background thread. Do you know
>   if the docs state this explicitly somewhere?

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013435-CH1-SW13) of `NSURLSession.delegateQueue`:

> All delegate method calls and completion handlers related to the session are performed on this queue.

If you don't explicitly set the `delegateQueue` on creation of the session

> ...the session creates a serial operation queue for performing all delegate method calls and completion handler calls.

Comment: what is this useful for? please complete answer / add examples